# Cover predicate for two lists

Tags: list, prolog

So I'm making a countdown game and I want to check whether a list has elements of another list.

Given two lists, checks whether the second list covers the first, that is it checks whether every item that occurs K times in the first list also occurs at least K times in the second:

Examples

```
cover([a,e,i,o], [m,o,n,k,e,y,b,r,a,i,n]).
Yes

cover([e,e,l], [h,e,l,l,o]).
no
```

I have following a paper which is giving me loads of practice examples, I've done okay so far but this one has me at a bit of a standstill.

I have written this,

```
cover([],_).
cover([Head|Tail], List2):-
    member(Head, List2),
    cover(Tail, List2).
```

Problem is, it is not considering the K number of times in the list,

I've been scratching my head for hours,
any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **very close** to a solution!

To solve it fully, consider a slight *generalization* of `member/2`: The building block we shall use in this case is a lot like `member/2`, but with the following twist: We let the **third argument** denote  what the *remaining* list is, I mean the list *without* the "member".

Traditionally, this predicate is called `select/3`, and that's a pretty bad name because it suggests that we can use the predicate only in one direction. That's rather *imperative*.

I will use a more descriptive, *declarative* name and call this **`selection/3`**.

Think about this **relation** like this:

```
selection(E, [E|Ls], Ls).
selection(E, [L|Ls], [L|Rest]) :-
        selection(E, Ls, Rest).
```

You can think of `member/2` as a special case of `selection/3`, because we could define `member/2` in terms of `selection/3`, not caring about the remaining list:

```
member(E, Ls) :- selection(E, Ls, _).
```

Using `selection/3`, we can write:

```
list_cover([], _).
list_cover([L|Ls], Cs0) :-
        selection(L, Cs0, Cs),
        list_cover(Ls, Cs).
```

We can read the second clause as follows:

> **If** `L` is a member of `Cs0`, and `Cs` is the remaining list (i.e., `Cs0` without `L`), *and* `Cs` covers `Ls`, **then** `Cs0` covers `[L|Ls]`.

Note the naming convention, which ideally makes clear what  each argument stands for. In our case, the *second* argument is the *covering* list. Calling this simply `cover/2` would not make clear which of the arguments actually denotes the cover.

Sample queries and answers:

```
?- list_cover([a,e,i,o], [m,o,n,k,e,y,b,r,a,i,n]).
true .

?- list_cover([a,a,a], [a,a]).
false.

?- list_cover([a,a,a], [a,a,b,a]).
true .
```

And further:

```
?- list_cover(Ls, Cs).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [_1900],
Cs = [_1900|_1908] ;
Ls = [_1900, _1912],
Cs = [_1900, _1912|_1920] .
```

Pretty cool, no? It's quite general!